# Automating a command line exe with powershell

Tags: powershell

We have a very old tool that our company uses that runs some basic command line scripts to deploy some text files to our servers. It works well, but the process is repetitive.

When the exe runs it does 3 prompts...
"Enter The destination Folder"
"Enter The Server"
"Enter the Password"

We have to do this for about 10 servers, and its sitting there doing a lot of copy paste. Since this process was created everything has been standardized.

So I wanted to make a powershell script that ran the exe process and basically pasted the 3 pieces of information and just loop the server name..

I THOUGHT I had the process working using SendKeys... but even though it appeared to work in every way... it never ACTUALLY did anything. So im not sure if the exe did not like send keys or what.

So then I resolved to trying to use Send Keys outside of Windows forms and launch cmd.exe and run it that way.

That way seemed to work as well, but the results were the same, the files were never updated.

If I did this process manually in powerhsell they worked fine though.

My final attempt was doing this.

```
try {
  $MyProcess = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process

  $MyProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "c:\MyProcess.exe"
  $MyProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "arguments for process"
  $MyProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = $false
  $MyProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = $true
  $MyProcess.Start()
  $StdIn = $MyProcess.StandardInput

  $StdIn.WriteLine($destinationFolder)
  $StdIn.WriteLine($server)
  $StdIn.WriteLine($password)
} finally {
  if($StdIn) {
    $StdIn.Close()
  }
```

This process DOES update the files, however I cannot loop it, because as soon as the first exe finishes the script crashes with the error

"Cannot Read Keys when Either application does not have a console or when a console inout has been redirected"

I am looking for a way to get this to work...

Comment: The code you posted seems to work fine. The error message you gave is thrown from the `Console.ReadKey` function. Are you using this method anywhere in your script? I tested your script by changing the process to "cmd.exe" and replacing `$password` with `"exit"` to close the window and I can't find any issues with it.

Comment: As an aside: `$destinationFolder, $server, $password | c:\MyProcess.exe arguments for process` should be sufficient to invoke your executable as intended.

Comment: The above implicitly executes the command _synchronously_. If that is the intent and you  want to stick with your original approach, you must add `$MyProcess.WaitForExit()`

Comment: I dont care HOW i do it, but ihave done wait for exit too and still get the crash

Comment: So does it also crash with `$destinationFolder, $server, $password | c:\MyProcess.exe arguments for process`? Please also add relevant additional code to the question (the  loop and the call that causes the error).

Comment: yes it still has the error..

Comment: I have removed all the loops, the only other information is the name of the folder and the server, im starting with one server just to see if this even works.